# geom_boxplot custom color for quantiles

Tags: ggplot2, boxplot, geom

I have a simple ggplot boxplot like in this example

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- ToothGrowth

ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)

p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(~supp)
p
```

**Goal:**

I want the boxes of the quantiles in different colors, as seen in the image below.

One Hint could be this link:
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html.

But I'm not shure how to implement this for the ractangles. In addition I have in my plots a facid_grid, and there the coloration should work as well. Here can you see what I want to achieve in the end.

[image: This is what it should look like]

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do like this: First, calculate the `median`, first and third quartile (`quart1` and `quart3`) for `ToothGrowth`, grouped by `supp` and `dose`. Afterwards you can fill in the lower and upper rectangles of the boxplots. Since you wanted four different colors, I added four different rectangles.

```
ToothGrowth <- ToothGrowth %>% mutate(dose = factor(dose)) %>% group_by(supp, dose) %>% 
  mutate(median = median(len), quart1 = quantile(len, 0.25), quart3 = quantile(len, 0.75))

ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(dose, len)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.6) +
  facet_grid(~supp) +
  geom_rect(data = subset(ToothGrowth, supp == "OJ"), 
            aes(xmin = as.numeric(dose) - 0.3, xmax = as.numeric(dose) + 0.3, ymin = quart1, ymax = median), 
            fill = "#008AA7", color = "black") +
  geom_rect(data = subset(ToothGrowth, supp == "VC"), 
            aes(xmin = as.numeric(dose) - 0.3, xmax = as.numeric(dose) + 0.3, ymin = quart1, ymax = median), 
            fill = "#005645", color = "black") +
  geom_rect(data = subset(ToothGrowth, supp == "OJ"), 
            aes(xmin = as.numeric(dose) - 0.3, xmax = as.numeric(dose) + 0.3, ymin = median, ymax = quart3), 
            fill = "#A2EFFD", color = "black") +
  geom_rect(data = subset(ToothGrowth, supp == "VC"), 
            aes(xmin = as.numeric(dose) - 0.3, xmax = as.numeric(dose) + 0.3, ymin = median, ymax = quart3), 
            fill = "#90AC9E", color = "black")
```

Which gives the following plot:

[image]

Comment: This is wonderfull :-) Is there a way to calculate the offset (here it is `0.3`) for my actual plot? Since I have to adjust it to `0.375` to completely cover the original

Comment: The offset (here 0.3) should each be half of the specified width with geom_boxplot (here 0.6)